# How to update this PHP regex to not allow more than 10 digits in a phone number?

Tags: php, regex, forms, validation, preg-match

I'm using the following regex to ensure a valid phone number is entered. It currently does not flag an error if more than 10 digits are entered.

How can this be fixed?

```
public function phoneNumber($value) {
    if (preg_match("/^\(?[0-9]{3}\)? *-? *[0-9]{3} *-? *[0-9]{4}$/", $value)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Here's a test case that is currently showing up as a valid phone number, when it shouldn't:

> 35353535355535555555

Comment: fyi, you can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]` and `\s` instead of a blank space

Comment: Looks good to me... can you please provide an example input string that should not be allowed, that is being allowed?

Comment: It is working for me... what php are u using ?

Comment: @Patashu Are you sure that `\s == ' '`?  I understand it also matches tabs and linebreaks, so might not be analagous/appropriate to replace OP's literal space with `\s`.  And just as an aside, you're right re `[0-9] == \d` but IMHO the `[0-9]` is more immediately obvious in meaning than `\d`, to future developers who may be less familar with regex syntax.

Comment: Reduce the input to nothing but digits, then test against that, formatting should not be part of the validation if you're only interested in the quantity of numbers.

Comment: Note that you can simplify the function like so: `return !!preg_match(....);`

Comment: @Sepster It matches all kinds of whitespace, so it's more generic = better

Comment: @Kolink Nice `not-not`

Comment: Why are you escaping the parens, but nothing else?  `\(`.  Also, don't you want `(?:` instead of `(?` for a non-capturing grouping?

Comment: @Patashu rarely does "more generic" equate "better" in a regex! ;-)  But yes, it is certainly appropriate sometimes, I just don't think we should blindly state that they're the same thing because they're not.

Comment: @Jessemon `\(?` matches an optional open parens, which is what was wanted.

Comment: @Sepster Notice I said 'you can use' not 'is equivalent'. I think that `\d` will match unicode digits in addition to ascii ones (though I've never had to test this)

Comment: @Jessemon because the `\(?` and `\)?` are literals for an area code, where the trailing `?` is to represent these as optional (ie, _not_ trying to define a non-capturing group).

Comment: @Kolink, thanks.  Having `?` mean more than one thing in a regex is confusing.

Comment: Provide some phone number that are valid and some not valid. Then someone can help you.

Comment: @Patashu you _can use_ eg `.*` too, if generality is what's required.  But it wouldn't make the regex any better.  OK, yes, that's just an extreme to make my point...  But notice also I said "_might not_ be analagous/appropriate", I did not say that it _wasn't_ appropriate.  Don't be so defensive bro, was just qualifying your comment to make sure the OP and future readers don't misunderstand the comment.

Comment: @Jessemon No kidding, regexes in general are confusing :p

Comment: @Sepster Indeed, but some kind of generalities you'd be a fool to ignore (like unicode compliance, different-encodings compliance, treating spaces and tabs equivalently within reason, etc). Don't worry, I'm just clarifying my position :)

Comment: @Patashu if `\s` provides generality across encodings where a literal space does not, then that's an _excellent_ reason to use `\s`, but only so long as tabs/line-endings are acceptable.  In this case though, I doubt line-endings at least are acceptable in the middle of a phone number.  But perhaps the anchors take care of that anyhow, reducing the `\s` to whitespace and tabs only (so long as no multi-line option specified!).  We're both making good points I think ;-)

Comment: Silly question, but have you actually confirmed that your input `$value` contains what you think it does at this point?  Perhaps a `var_dump ($value);` immediately prior to your `...preg_match...` line will reveal a bug earlier in your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're only interested in the numbers, you can filter out everything else and check the result:

```
public function phoneNumber($value) {
    $filtered = preg_replace("/\D/","",$value);
    return strlen($filtered) == 10;
}
```

Comment: I like this answer.  Rip out everything but the digits.

Comment: +1 Nice, clear, maintainable, elegant solution. Although I'm pretty sure this is still _functionally_ analogous to what the OPs original code was actually doing?

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up re falsy `0`. This is what happens when you send a .NET coder to a PHP gun-fight ;-)  So just as an exercise in academia, I'm still not clear as to why the OP's code doesn't work as expected... that regex looks sound to me (and the regex testers I've tested it in).

Comment: Not so good if someone adds an extension or throws in a foreign number.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to filter out foreign numbers or numbers with extensions. Here's an example that I use for converting common numbers for a specific format for CRM injection. Includes spam scoring.

```
<?php
    function phoneNumber($value) {
        $phoneScore = 0;
        $numbers = preg_replace('![^0-9]!','',$value);
        //if it's too small to be a US number, then ramp it up.
        if (!empty($value)&&(strlen($numbers) < 10)){
            $phoneScore = $phoneScore + 3;
        } elseif (empty($value)){
            $phoneScore = $phoneScore + 10;     
        }
        return $phoneScore;
    }

    $numbers = array(
    '(911 -535 -3535',
    '800.555.1212',
    '800  458 2180',
    '800 - 458 2180',
    '800 - 458-2180',
    '',
    '800-555-1212 ext# 212',
    '+49 (0)69 974640',
    '+86 (021) 5466-2808',
    '+66 (02) 261-3525',
    '+44 (020) 7626-0224',
    '123456',
    );

    $patterns = array('![^0-9xX#+]!','!-+!','!-?[xX#]-?!','!#+!','!#!','!^-!');
    $replacements = array("-","-",'#','#',' #','');

    foreach ($numbers as $value){
        $score = phoneNumber($value);
        $clean_num = preg_replace($patterns,$replacements,$value);
        echo "$value = Score $score.<br />\n Cleaned Number = $clean_num<br />\n<br />\n";
    }

?>
```

Output looks like this:

> (911 -535 -3535 = Score 0. Cleaned Number = 911-535-3535
>
> 800.555.1212 = Score 0. Cleaned Number = 800-555-1212
>
> 800 458 2180 = Score 0. Cleaned Number = 800-458-2180
>
> 800 - 458 2180 = Score 0. Cleaned Number = 800-458-2180
>
> 800 - 458-2180 = Score 0. Cleaned Number = 800-458-2180
>
> = Score 10. Cleaned Number =
>
> 800-555-1212 ext# 212 = Score 0. Cleaned Number = 800-555-1212 #212
>
> +49 (0)69 974640 = Score 0. Cleaned Number = +49-0-69-974640
>
> +86 (021) 5466-2808 = Score 0. Cleaned Number = +86-021-5466-2808
>
> +66 (02) 261-3525 = Score 0. Cleaned Number = +66-02-261-3525
>
> +44 (020) 7626-0224 = Score 0. Cleaned Number = +44-020-7626-0224
>
> 123456 = Score 3. Cleaned Number = 123456